# textarea to JSON file not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

I am developing a "flickr-like" webpage where users can register, post images, and comment on then.
The thing is that I have write some come which will take the textarea value from the user whos writing the comment, and then posting that comment in the JSON server (i am using an API Rest JSON).
Buut, my problem is that if the text from the comment is "large" (i.e. hello this is a new comment) the system does not post anything, or if it does, after a lots of refresh. Instead, if the comment is "a", the sistem works perfectly.
What I am doing wrong here?

My php code where the textarea is:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un comentario..." id='comment-section' rows="3"></textarea>
                                <br>
                                <button type="button" class="btn  btn-outline-success float-center" id='boton-publicar' onclick="postComment()">Publicar</button>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <hr>
                                <div id="comments-container">
                                    <ul class="media-list">


                                            <!--bloque de comentario-->




                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

(I have an onclick() when the "Publish" button is engaged).

My JS code:

```
function postComment() {
let userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
let date = new Date().toISOString();
let texto = $("#comment-section").val();
let comentario = { user: userId, photoId: id, text: texto, date: date};


fetch(`http://localhost:3000/comments/`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(comentario),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + getToken(),
    },

});
location.reload();
```

}

And lastly, my JSON file where the comments means to be send to:

```
"comments": [
{
  "user": "9",
  "photoId": "3",
  "text": "esto es un comentario largo de prueba",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:03:59.126Z",
  "id": 1
},
{
  "user": "9",
  "photoId": "5",
  "text": "a",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:04:30.646Z",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "user": "9",
  "photoId": "5",
  "text": "b",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:06:43.293Z",
  "id": 3
},
{
  "user": "9",
  "photoId": "5",
  "text": "c",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:07:18.010Z",
  "id": 4
},
{
  "user": "9",
  "photoId": "5",
  "text": "d",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:07:21.499Z",
  "id": 5
},
{
  "user": "6",
  "photoId": "3",
  "text": "comentario de admin",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:09:08.279Z",
  "id": 6
},
{
  "user": "6",
  "photoId": "2",
  "text": "admincom",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:18:24.821Z",
  "id": 7
},
{
  "user": "6",
  "photoId": "2",
  "text": "admincom2",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:18:38.515Z",
  "id": 8
},
{
  "user": "6",
  "photoId": "2",
  "text": "admincom3",
  "date": "2020-05-26T09:18:51.759Z",
  "id": 9
}
```

],

Comment: Where is your `textarea` element on HTML?

Comment: @Jesper Martinez my bad, already edited with my textarea and so !